# Use an array as select form

Tags: php

I am a beginner and I have written a piece of code to use an array values inside a select form, but I don't know how to get the chosen value.
What I have :

```
$list = '<select><option>' .implode('</option><option>',$apn).'</option></select>';
```

Now I would like to get the name of the chosen value but I don't know how.I tried to add

```
<select name="test">
```

to my select form and get it with

```
echo $_POST['test']
```

but it does not work.
Thank you !

Comment: What is your `<form>` method?

Comment: @analou, does it work ?

Comment: No answer for the form tag?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php $myArray = array(1 => 'red', 2 => 'blue'); ?>

  <select name="theName">
  <?php
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) { ?>
         <option value="<?php $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
 <?php  } ?>
  </select>
```

Basically, you are looping through the option value with a foreach statement and assigning the key as the value.

You then get the chosen value with name 'theName'... `echo $_POST['theName'];`

Comment: (what you have would be invalid as is, need a few more php tags or wrap the html into their $list variable like in the example)

Comment: this is how I want to display the chosen value and it doesn't work :<input type="text" name="ip_address[]"> <p class='numberinputdetails'><?php echo $_POST['test']; ?> </p>

Comment: You don't need `value`, it uses the text in between `option` tags if there is no `value` and OP did that with `implode`.

Comment: maybe this is the way I want to display it that doesn't work?